# Como ler tres valores na mesma linha? C#

Tags: c#

Como consigo colocar três valores na mesma linha separados por espaço no C#?E depois trabalhar com elas?

**Problema: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1079**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o String.Split para separar em espaços e depois converter para array de decimal.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace Exemplo
{
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Múltiplos valores em uma linha");
            string inp = Console.ReadLine();
            decimal [] valores = inp.Split(' ').Select(x=> decimal.Parse(x)).ToArray();//Ou foreach se preferir.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",valores));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma maneira bem fácil de se fazer:

```
using System;

namespace uri
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            string[] texto = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ");
            int n1 = int.Parse(texto[0]), n2 = int.Parse(texto[1]), n3 = int.Parse(texto[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("n1 = "+n1+", n2 = "+n2+", n3 = "+n3);        
        }
    }
}
```